# How to fetch data from mySQL and view in Modal

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to show some records from my table columns named `tid` and `ketprob` by showing Modal when clicking on a link. The modal and query looks fine (checked by echoing last_query), but the modal is showing no data... Please help me :(

JS Code:

```
$('#showdata').on('click', '.item-info', function(){
  var tid = $(this).attr('data');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'get',
    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>repeatproblem/infoReprob',
    data: {tid:tid},
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      var html = '';
      var i;
      for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        html +='<p>'+data[i].tid+'</p>'+
        '<p>'+data[i].ketprob+'</p>';
      }
      $('#infoModal').modal('show');
      $('#view_errorcode').html(html);
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('Gagal Info Kode Error!');
    }
  });
});
```

My Controller:

```
public function infoReprob(){ 
    $result = $this->m->infoReprob(); 
    echo json_encode($result); 
}
```

My Model:

```
public function infoReprob(){
    $tid = $this->input->get('tid');
    $this->db->select('tid, ketprob')->where('tid', $tid);
    $query = $this->db->get('histprob');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `return $query->row();` syntax in your model if this condition is true: `$query->num_rows() > 0`, so that means your model will return the object representation of the first row of the query and the `$result` variable in your controller below will be an object with two properties: `tid` and `ketprob`

```
public function infoReprob(){ 
    $result = $this->m->infoReprob(); 
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Now have a look at your ajax call success callback function

```
success: function(data){
    var html = '';
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        html +='<p>'+data[i].tid+'</p>'+
        '<p>'+data[i].ketprob+'</p>';
    }
    $('#infoModal').modal('show');
    $('#view_errorcode').html(html);
}
```

Since your controller above uses `echo json_encode($result);` syntax, your ajax call will return the json representation of `$result` variable and the `data` variable in your success callback function above will be like below

```
{ "tid": "1", "ketprob": "abc" }
```

The problem is, `data.length` in your ajax success callback function will be undefined because `data` isn't an array, so the `for` loop won't be executed and `html` will be an empty string, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87s4rLx3/). That's why your modal is showing no data.

To fix the problem, I'd suggest changing your model code as below

```
public function infoReprob(){
    $tid = $this->input->get('tid');
    $this->db->select('tid, ketprob')->where('tid', $tid);
    $query = $this->db->get('histprob');
    return $query->result();
}
```

By using `return $query->result();` syntax, your model will always return an array of object. As the result, your ajax call will return a json like this

```
[ { "tid": "1", "ketprob": "abc" } ]
```

which is a json array, so `data.length` in your ajax success callback function won't be undefined and your modal will show the data. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hbyw7zd/), you'll see that the `html` variable is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use `echo $query->row();` instead of `return $query->row();`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Changed to echo instead of return, but shows JS Error alert.

Comment: Perhaps remove `dataType: 'json'` - data received from a table more often than not isn't correct JSON data.

Comment: @DamianCzapiewski Removed json and showing long full page text "undefined"

Comment: @Vickel This code has already jsoned in my Controller: 


public function infoReprob(){
  $result = $this->m->infoReprob();
  echo json_encode($result);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing **return $query->row();** to **return $query->result();**

Going to learn about this. Or can anybody tell about the different.. Thanks

```
public function infoReprob(){
    $tid = $this->input->get('tid');
    $this->db->select('tid, ketprob')->where('tid', $tid);
    $query = $this->db->get('histprob');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-query-row-and-query-resulty-in-codeigniter :)

Comment: As explained [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html), the difference is `$query->row()` returns an **object** and `$query->result()` returns an **array of objects**. See my answer to understand why `$query->row()` doesn't work but `$query->result()` works in your code.